# why is not margin collapning occur in this example

Tags: html, version-control

```
What I don't really understand here is why margin collapse doesn't occur vertically between each definition list(dl). As you can see in style selector "#sweden dl" below I have set
```

margin:10px 20px; this mean margin-top and margin-bottom 10px for each dl and margin-left and margin-right 20px for each dl. So here we would have adjecent margins of 10px between margin-top and margin-bottom for the first dl and the same for the second dl.

When I run this in a browser it looks like the margin vertically between each dl and the margin besides each dl have the same width in this case 20px.

So according to margin collapse the verically margin between dl would only be 10px and not 20px as it looks now in the browser.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body
            {
                font-family:Arial, sans-serif;
                font-size:small;
                padding:0;
                margin:0;
            }

            #sweden
            {
                float:left;
                width:300px;
                padding:10px 0;
                margin:1px;
                border:2px solid #C8CDD2;
            }

            #sweden dl /* block element */
            {
                float:left;
                margin:10px 20px;
                padding:0;
                background:green;
            }

            #sweden dt   /* block element */
            {
               float:right;
                margin:0;
                padding:0;
                font-size:130%;
                letter-spacing:1px;
                color:#627081;
                width:162px;    
                background:blue;
            }

            #sweden dd
            {
               margin:0;  /*Will float around the image */
               font-size:85%;  
               line-height:1.5em;
               color:#666;
               background:red;
            }

            #sweden dd.img img
            {
               float:left;
               margin: 0 8px 0 0;
               padding:4px;
               border:1px solid #D9E0E6;
               border-bottom-color:#C8CDD2;
               border-right-color:#C8CDD2;
               background:#fff;
           }

           #sweden dl dd.img
           {
              margin:0;
              padding:0;
           } 
        </style>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>Chapter 3</title>
    </head>
    <body>
   <div id="sweden">
          <dl>
             <dt>Stockholm</dt>
             <dd class="img"><img src="img/gamlastan.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla 
                Stan" /></dd>    
             <dd>This was taken in Gamla Stan.</dd>
          </dl>

          <dl class="alt">
             <dt>Gamla Uppsala</dt>
            <dd class="img"><img src="img/uppsala.jpg" width="80" height="80" alt="Gamla 
               Uppsala" /></dd>
            <dd>The first three Swedish kings are buried here, under ancient burial mounds. 
            </dd>
          </dl>

          <dl>
             <dt>Perpetual Sun</dt>
             <dd class="img"><img src="img/watch.jpg" width="80" height="80" 
                alt="Wristwatch" /></dd>
             <dd>During the summer months, the sun takes forever to go down. this is a good 
                thing.</dd>
          </dl>
       </div>
   </body>
```

//Tony

Answer (score 0, accepted):

do not have their margins collapsed: on floated element

The verically margin between dl will be 20px

by

```
margin-top:10px;
margin-bottom:10px;
```

use

```
margin:0px 20px 10px 20px;
```

Comment: But you have adjecent margin between margin-top and margin-bottom of 10px each so why don't you get 10px. That's how adjecent margin collapse works.

Comment: that is, margin-bottom of first(10px) + margin-top of second(10px)
gives you a combined margin of 20 px

Comment: So according to me would we get only 10px of margin becuse of margin collapse. Do you relly know what I mean with margin collapse ?

Comment: if you for example have this markup <p>one</p>
<p>two</p>
<p>three</p> with this styling for p
{
    margin:10px 0;
} you would get 10px between the p and not 20px

Comment: There are other situations where elements do not have their margins collapsed:

    floated elements
    absolutely positioned elements
    inline-block elements
    elements with overflow set to anything other than visible (They do not collapse margins with their children.)
    cleared elements (They do not collapse their top margins with their parent block’s bottom margin.)
    the root element

Comment: So do you mean that the reason for not margin collapse occur was that the dl element was floating.

Comment: Yes it was the float. If I removed the float on selector "#sweden dl" I got margin 10px insted of the 20px I had when we have float on #sweden dl.